# Error at calling my app components Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i was creating my welcome page, and, when it was finished, i decided to organize the page components in diferent files. Thats the welcome page code:

```
  class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final globalVariables = GlobalVariables();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TxtInfo(),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: globalVariables.height * 0.55,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  kBlueBackground,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: globalVariables.width * 0.76,
                    ),
                    height: globalVariables.height * 0.45,
                    child: Buttons(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here its the top part of the page:

```
class TxtInfo extends StatelessWidget {
final globalVariables = GlobalVariables();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            width: globalVariables.width * 0.76,
            height: globalVariables.height * 0.45,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Txt(
                  txt: 'Bem-Vindo!',
                  txtStyle: kTitleTextStyle,
                ),
                Txt(
                  txt: 'Acesse a sua conta para continuar',
                  txtStyle: kBlackParagraphTextStyle,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And here the second part:

```
class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
  final globalVariables = GlobalVariables();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Button(
          height: globalVariables.height,
          txt: 'Criar conta agora',
          txtStyle: kWhiteButtonTextStyle,
          buttonColor: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: globalVariables.navigateToCreateAccountPage,
        ),
        Button(
          height: globalVariables.height,
          txt: 'Entrar',
          txtStyle: kBlackButtonTextStyle,
          buttonColor: kWhiteColor,
          onPressed: globalVariables.navigateToLoginPage,
        ),
        Txt(
          txt: 'ou',
          txtStyle: kWhiteParagraphTextStyle,
        ),
        SocialButton(
          height: globalVariables.height,
          direct: kFacebookIcon,
          txt: 'Entar com Facebook',
          txtStyle: kFacebookButtonTextStyle,
          buttonColor: kWhiteColor,
        ),
        SocialButton(
          height: globalVariables.height,
          direct: kGoogleIcon,
          txt: 'Entrar com Google',
          txtStyle: kGoogleButtonTextStyle,
          buttonColor: kWhiteColor,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here it is the global variables file code:

```
class GlobalVariables extends StatelessWidget {
  get navigateToLoginPage => null;
  get navigateToCreateAccountPage => null;

  get width => null;
  get height => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    navigateToLoginPage() {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
      );
    }

    navigateToCreateAccountPage() {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccountPage()),
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

I imported everything that i need in theese classes, the sintax is perfect, but the emulator show me this error:

"NoSuchMethodError: The method '*' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: *(0.55)"

Comment: You are accessing 'null' values when calling height and width. `get width => null;`

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was it, but how can i set an empty value in theese getters?

Comment: Why do you want the getter to be empty? Don't you want to access a real value when using it in other places? It doesn't make sense to use a getter and give it a null value or leave it as undefined.

Comment: I was trying to create a separated file for global vars and consts, but i couldnt find a way to implement theese parameters in other classes without using a getter, do you know some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just put them in a class and define your methods and properties there. One way of doing so:

```
class GlobalVariables {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;

  navigateToLoginPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
      );
    }

void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
  }
}
```

You only need to call the `init` method once for every page you create, then you can access the properties, for example:

```
 class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalVariables().init(context);

    final globalVariables = GlobalVariables();

    double width = GlobalVariables.screenWidth;

return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                globalVariables.navigateToLoginPage(context);
              }
            )
           Text("$width")
        ],)
      
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me :D, but one more question, there is another way to access the `screenWidth` or `screenHeight` from GlobalVariables without creating another variable in all classes, like `double width = GlobalVariables.screenWidth`?

Comment: Just create a `static Size screen;` and assign `screen = _mediaQueryData.size;` then to access just do `final screens = GlobalVariables.screen;` eg: `screens.width`